# Display of various plots with shared x-axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I'm currently trying to have a plot which displays various trajectories of time series with a shared x-axis (time).

```
time <- seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=101)

X1 <- runif(101)
X2 <- runif(101)
X3 <- runif(101)

par(mfcol=c(3,1))
plot(time,X1,type="l")
plot(time,X2,type="l")
plot(time,X3,type="l")
```

This creates the output [image: output]

I want the three plots in this example to be stacked onto each other with only one x-axis "time". In addition I want the labels of the y-axis "X1", "X2" and "X3" to stay left of the corresponding plot.

I really would appreciate any help and suggestions!

PS: I also already know about the "trick" to remove the x-axis from the two plots at the top, but this makes it hard to vary the number of plots; say I have "X1", "X2", "X3" and "X4" I would have to recalculate the place of the labels of the y-axis and this seems quite hard to me.

**Edit:** This is an exampe of how it should look:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggplot` you can do this quite easily by first putting your data into a data frame formatted like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(value = c(X1, X2, X3), 
                 label = rep(c("X1", "X2", "X3"), each = 101),
                 time  = rep(time, 3))
```

And the plotting code looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(y = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0.1)) +
  facet_grid(label ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free_y") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement  = "outside",
        panel.spacing    = unit(0, "lines"),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA))
```

[image]

Note that as requested, the plotting code remains the same if you add an extra variable - you just update your data frame to include it. So, for example, I can add the variable `X4` like this:

```r
X4 <- rnorm(101, mean = 0, sd = 10)

df <- rbind(df, data.frame(value = X4, label = rep("X4", 101), time = time))
```

And now running the exact same plotting code produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks good, but unfortunately the y-axis behaves static.. do you know how to set up an individual scale of the y-axis for each plot? For example if `X3 <- rnorm(101, mean=0, sd=10)`, and X1 and X2 stay the same, the plots of X1 and X2 are barely visible, because of the big scale of X3.

Comment: @nomeal Sure, just add `scales = "free_y"` to the `facet_grid` call.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! Do you know how I get it to look like in the example I have uploaded?

Comment: @nomeal See my update which adds some theme elements to better match the look of your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would have one last question: How do I change the order of X1 to X4, for example to X4, X3, X2, X1 (starting from the top). If I change the order in the definition of the data frame it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lattice` package:

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(X1, X2, X3), 
                 label = rep(c("X1", "X2", "X3"), each = 101),
                 time  = rep(time, 3))

library(lattice)
xyplot(value~time|label,data=df,type="l",
       scales=list(y=list(relation="free")),
       layout=c(1,4))
```

[image]

Comment: I have added an example of how it should look. Do you know how I achieve this?